# Dispatch is not a function in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

MY action

```
    const fetchDataApi = (getState) => {
        let { data } = getState()
        return axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london,uk&appid=26aacf43db7ecfa2ecd85500eaee9920').then(thunkdata => {
            console.log(thunkdata)
            return {
                [data]: thunkdata
            }
        })
    }

const fetchgetDataCall = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return dispatch(fetchDataApi(getState))
    }

}


export const getData = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchgetDataCall())
    return {
        type: actionTypes.GETDATA,

    }
}
```

In action.js i want to get data from my whether api and store in data,  so i am using getstate to get data variable and assign data to it

My calender Component where i am  connecting my callender to actionType

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import 'moment/locale/it.js';
import { DatePicker, DatePickerInput } from 'rc-datepicker';
// import { ca } from 'date-fns/esm/locale';
import 'rc-datepicker/lib/style.css';


import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import  { getData } from '../store/actions/actions'

const date = '2015-06-26' // or Date or Moment.js


class Callender extends Component {
    //These is a method  es7

    onChangeandler = (jsDate, dateString, event) => {
        // event.preventDefault()
        console.log("[we are lokking at js date]",jsDate);
        this.props.getWether();
        console.log("[we are seeing the props storeDta]",this.props.storeData);

    }

    //Next method 

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DatePicker onChange={this.onChangeandler} value={date} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state  =>({
    storeData: state.data
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)  =>({
    getWether: () => dispatch(getData())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Callender)
```

My reducer

```
import  * as actionType from '../actions/actionTypes';

    const intialState ={
        time:null,
        day:null,
        data:null
    }

    // reducer 
    const reducer = (state=intialState, action) =>{
        switch(action.type){
            case actionType.GETDATA:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    data:action.data
                }
            case actionType.POSTDATA:
                return {
                    ...state
                }
            default : 
              return {
                  ...state
              }

        }
    }


    export default  reducer;
```

actionTypes.js

```
export const  POSTDATA="POSTDATA";
export const GETDATA = "GETDATA";
```

1)I am calling my action creator in callender.js file

2) Where i am using thunk middleware to get data ,and store in  data variable  from redux store

3)I can't find the issue please help me

Comment: can you please show the code where you create the redux store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actions looks quite weird. The `getData` action creator disptaches `fetchgetDataCall` which dispatches `fetchDataApi` and that returns just some object `{ [data]: thunkdata}` where property `data` are probably null in that moment. Hence there are not any properties `type` or `data` in your action object.

The second thing what your `getData` do is returning the object `{type: actionTypes.GETDATA}`, hence there is not any property `data` in your action object.

Try to do it something like this (updated according to @mbojko answer):

```js
const getData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london,uk&appid=26aacf43db7ecfa2ecd85500eaee9920').then(thunkdata => {
            return dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.GETDATA,
                data: thunkdata
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited code in my answer according to the @mbojko answer.

Comment: thanks a lot but what did i miss i taught i can split the code and use it propeller i  think did the same thing but divided the code what point i missed

Answer (score 1):

Compare your function signature

```
export const getData = (dispatch) => {
```

With how you call it:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)  =>({
    getWether: () => dispatch(getData())
})
```

The argument is missing (therefore `dispatch` is not defined and obviously not a function).

Should be `dispatch(getData(dispatch))`, probably.

Comment: yes i tried that then i got error  Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Comment: Because your `fetchgetDataCall` returns a function instead of a plain object.

Comment: sorry to bother you but i excuted the function with dispatch which in turn is returning the object